# How to iterate over a table cells using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to jQuery and I am trying to learn it. I want to iterate over a `9 * 9` grid alerting the values of the `input` boxes(total 81), row wise, column wise and grid `3 * 3` wise.

Here is what I have tried:

```
$("#checkBox").change(function () {
        if (this.checked) {
            $('table tr').each(function () {
                alert($(this).td.input.val());
            });
            $('table tr').each(function () {
                alert($(this).td.input.val());
            });
        } else {
            alert("Check Box is unchecked. AutoCheck is disabled.");
        }
    });
```

Only `else alert` is working. Any comment or guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part `$(this).td.input.val()` of your code will raise error since jquery object does not contains a property called `td`.

Try,

```
 //The following snippet would alert the text inside of each td
 $('table tr td').each(function () {
    alert($(this).text());
 });

 //The following snippet would alert the value of each input each td
 $('table tr td input').each(function () {
    alert($(this).val());
 });
```

If you want to iterate row wise then try,

```
 $('table tr').each(function () {
    $(this).find('td').each(function(){
     $(this).find(':input').each(function(){
         alert($(this).val()); 
     });  
    });
 });
```

Comment: @Rajaprabhu Aravindasamy Snippet 2 is giving alert messages for 81 times. I tried this already. What I wanted is row wise, column wise and each 3 * 3 grid wise alert.

Comment: @Phoenix I just edited the answer, check this out. But i am not sure what you are asking for..?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy I want to learn navigating through cells in different order of 9 * 9 Sudoku grid. Now I am able to navigate row wise. Thank you.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy Given some text is entered in one of the text boxes how to iterate over that cells row, column and grid?

Comment: i could not get you.. can you explain your situation a bit more..?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy Based on the cell's location in the 9 * 9 grid, where input has been changed, how to iterate over that particular cell's row, column and grid?

Comment: @Phoenix That's a nice question, Ask that as a new one, so that it may get many expert's attention. Or if you want a solution over here, then i am ready to write the code for that.. :)

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy If not a solution, can you provide guidance?

Comment: @Phoenix you have to bind change event for all the text boxes, and inside that events you can find its closest `tr`. by using `.closest()`. so after that we can iterate that particular row.